# Redirecting using $location upon successful login with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an Angular service that handles logging in to my SPA.

```js
myApp.service('loginService', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$resource', '$cookies', '$location', function($rootScope, $http, $resource, $cookies, $location) {
 
 this.validateEmail = function() {

  $http({
   url: myAppConfig.rootAPIUrl + 'Authenticate',
   params: {
    "playerId": $rootScope.data.emailId,
    "emailAddress": $rootScope.data.emailAddress
   },
   method: "POST"
  })
   .then(function(response) {

    if (response.data.Message == 'Success') {
     console.log('Login is successful.');
     $cookies.put('emailId', $rootScope.data.emailId);
     $location.path("#/game").replace();
    }

    $rootScope.msg = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
   }, function(response) {
    console.log('Error in $http in controller...');
  });

 }

}]);
```

Upon successful login, my conditions check out in the if block, I get the console msg, I get my cookie set, but the setting of the location path to '#/game' doesn't work. Any ideas on why?

Comment: are you wanting to redirect to `#/game` or `/#game`?

Comment: #/game, but even with that in the location path parameter, it doesn't redirect.

Comment: I don't think you need the hash in the path, unless you're set HTML5Mode to true, angular's $location.path method will do that for you. Have you tried just using `'/game'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass `'/game'` in the `$location.path`.
That's how it works for me.

Comment: Doh! Didn't realize Angular wanted the path without the hash. Thanks!